# Is there any requirement on font size and format of provisional patent application?

Tags: provisional-application

AFAIK, at USPTO, there are requirements on font size and format for non provisional application. Is there any requirement applying to provisional application?

Because I want to combine many unrelated inventions into a single provisional patent, and they limit it to 100 pages (or additional fee is added). So I will try to squeeze text size and format to increase text per page. I think since I will file electronically, the info will not lose, so I will write as small as possible (unlike filing in paper where small text can lose information)

Answer (score 1):

There are no requirements for provisional application filings beyond including a specification, and optionally drawings. There are no format requirements.  However, they scan and font that is small enough to be damaged by compression is a bad idea.

And seriously, it costs $40 per each additional 50 pages. Don't squeeze it.  It's not worth it.